# URL segment using Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, uri, segment

How can I implement a segment based url in laravel 4? 
I tried using it in laravel 3 like URI::segment(1) and it works. I converted my website using laravel 4 but the URI::segment(1) got an error. Any help?

Answer (score 32):

You need to use [Larvel Request segment](http://laravel.com/docs/requests#request-information)

```
Request::segment(1);
```

Comment: @Jimbo Here's a link, look for "Retrieve A Request URI Segment" http://laravel.com/docs/requests

Comment: Here's Laravel 5 approach to use segment http://stackoverflow.com/a/28574016/165084