# store and update in Laravel - which Request to use?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to Laravel and I have problems with storing and updating a Model.

Here is my store method

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{

    $input = Request::all();

    Klijent::create($input);

    return redirect('klijenti');

}
```

And I have to include `use Request;` to make it work.

Here is my update method

```
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //

    $klijent = Klijent::find($id);

    $klijent->update($request->all());

    return redirect('klijenti/'. $id);

}
```

And I have to include `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` to make it work.

But if I don't use first one I get this error when using store method:

```
Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::all() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context
```

If I don't use second one, I get this error when I use update method:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::all()
```

If I use both of them I get this error:

```
Cannot use Illuminate\Http\Request as Request because the name is already in use
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Request::all();](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28573860/laravel-requestall)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to make the call to non-static methods like

```
$input = $request->all();
```

in your first function. The second error is because `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request` does not have an `all` method to call. The third error is a namespace conflict, because you cannot have two classes with the same name in PHP.