# Undefined Method in Request::all()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I try the [getting started](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart) guide from Laravel.com.

There is a chapter *Creating the task*. There is `$request` a parameter of the callback and in the function `$request->all()` is used to get the GET-Parameters. But if I execute that callback I get the error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::all()

Here is my code:

```php
Route::post('/task', function(Request $request) {

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
    ]);

    if($validator->fails())
        redirect('/')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);

    $task = new Task();
    $task->name = $request['name'];
    $task->save();

    return redirect('/');
});
```

Comment: include `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` at the top of your file

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Your controller function gets injected an instance of **Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request** that forwards only static calls to underlying **request** object.

In order to fix that you need to import the underlying request class so that it is injected correctly. Add the following at the top of your **routes.php** file:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

or just call **Request::all()** instead of **$request->all()**.

Comment: Thank you but it would be nice if this information will be placed into this guide.

Comment: @Gerrit There is no explicit explanation, but there is a `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` in the routes file shown in the guide.

Comment: @Jed thank you, the ' OR ' part solved my problem :)

Answer (score 6):

Since this code is in the routes.php file, which is not namespaced, the `Request` object being injected into your closure is the `Request` facade, not the `Illuminate\Http\Request` object. The `Request` facade does not have an `all()` method.

Change your code to:

```
Route::post('/task', function(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    // code
});
```

Note: you generally don't fully qualify the `Request` object in Controller methods because Controllers usually add a `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` at the top. This is why your function definition in the routes file may look a little different than a controller method definition.

You can check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28573860/laravel-requestall) answer for a little more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following

```
$request::all()
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.