# How can I get illuminate\Http\Request for laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am getting below error in my project.

> Non-static method illuminate\Http\Request::all() should not be called statically . assuming $this from incompatible context

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Request::all() should not be called statically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28573860/laravel-requestall-should-not-be-called-statically)

Comment: I think this answer will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28574016/6809051

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided any code sample, but from the sounds of the error, looks like you're trying to call the `all()` method of `Illuminate\Http\Request`using the `$this->all()` syntax, but the method is static.

You might have a class extending the `Request` class, if that's the case you need to call it like `self::all()` or `parent::all()`