# Class App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request does not exist. Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.3 My ForgotPasswordController looks like that:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Base\BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\SendsPasswordResetEmails;

class ForgotPasswordController extends BaseController
{

use SendsPasswordResetEmails;
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}
public function showLinkRequestForm()
{
    $title = $this->title;
    $appName = $this->appName;
    $action = $this->action;
    return view('password.forgotPassword')->with(compact('title', 'appName', 'action'));
}
}
```

ResetPasswordController code :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Base\BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;

class ResetPasswordController extends BaseController
{

use ResetsPasswords;
 public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}

public function showResetForm(Request $request, $token = null)
{
    return view('passwords.resetPassword')->with(
        ['token' => $token, 'email' => $request->email]
    );
}
 public function reset(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'token' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ]);

    // Here we will attempt to reset the user's password. If it is successful we
    // will update the password on an actual user model and persist it to the
    // database. Otherwise we will parse the error and return the response.
    $response = $this->broker()->reset(
        $this->credentials($request), function ($user, $password) {
            $this->resetPassword($user, $password);
        }
    );

    // If the password was successfully reset, we will redirect the user back to
    // the application's home authenticated view. If there is an error we can
    // redirect them back to where they came from with their error message.
    return $response == Password::PASSWORD_RESET
                ? $this->sendResetResponse($response)
                : $this->sendResetFailedResponse($request, $response);
}

}
```

My Admin Route :

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Auth'], function() {
Route::get('/forgotpassword/reset', 'ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm');
Route::post('/forgotpassword/email', 'ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
Route::get('/password/reset/{token}', 'ResetPasswordController@showResetForm');
Route::post('/password/reset', 'ResetPasswordController@reset');
});
```

BaseController Code :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Base;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;


class BaseController extends Controller
{
protected $appName = 'Stackoverflow';
protected $title = 'Welcome to Stackoverflow';
protected $action;
}
```

I can send the link to my email, but once I click the link/button. 
It throws an error like above. Any idea ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Request::all() should not be called statically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28573860/laravel-requestall-should-not-be-called-statically)

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You are not using the required namespace, try to use the following in your controller:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

You are getting the error due to the fact that your script tries to load the `Request` class from the current namespace :`App\Http\Controllers\Auth`

[Request docs for Laravel 5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests)

Comment: it works, but throw another error, as u can see above my ForgotPasswordController return compact. at ResetPasswordContorller i try to return view with this code 
return view('password.resetPassword')->with(
            ['title' => $title 'appName' => $appName 'action' => $action 'token' => $token, 'email' => $request->email]
        );
result : yntax error, unexpected ''appName'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ']'

Comment: You missing ',' return view('password.resetPassword')->with( ['title' => $title, 'appName' => $appName, 'action' => $action, 'token' => $token, 'email' => $request->email] );

Comment: @ka_lin sorry, i forgot to add this (,) but now error Undefined variable: title

both Controller extends to BaseController.
here's my BaseController Code :
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Base;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;


class BaseController extends Controller
{
    protected $appName = 'stackoverflow';
    protected $title = 'Welcome to stackoverflow';
    protected $action;
}

Comment: You don't need title, make a layout(it will have the title) and you can overwrite it when extending. Appname should be from the config, and the action name can be resolved using the HTML facade (see http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/190/generating-a-html-link-to-a-named-route )

Comment: @ka_lin but I can't, my all controller linked to there, all my layout using call $appName/$title. sorry.

any other solution ?

Comment: Make you own base controller (`MyBaseController`) which extends `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\BaseController` and assign variables there (P.S in `MyBaseController` construct call `parent::__construct()` if the BaseController has one, I don't remember and don't have a project to check). Then all controllers should extend `MyBaseController`

Comment: Excelent. Worked like charm

Comment: I still get this error with "use Illuminate\Http\Request;" in my Controller class, copy-pasted from the documentation yet I get this error