# Edit / Update database Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, crud

I am struggling to update data in the database with an edit form and couldn't find anything online that fits the logic of my setup.

I have a add button, delete button and an edit button. Adding and Deleting works but Editing does not update the data.

Any help would be appreciated as I have tried multiple methods with no success.

Thank you in advance.

View:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <div class="container flex-center">
        <div class="row col-md-8 flex-column">
            <h1>Edit a link</h1>
            @foreach ($links as $link)
            <form action="{{ url('link/'.$link->id) }}" method="POST">
              {!! csrf_field() !!}
              @method('PUT')
                @if ($errors->any())
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                        Please fix the following errors
                    </div>
                @endif

                <h3 class="edit-link-title">{{ $link->title }}</h3>
                {!! csrf_field() !!}
                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('title') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                    <label for="title">Title</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Title" value="{{ $link->title }}">
                    @if($errors->has('title'))
                        <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('title') }}</span>
                    @endif
                </div>
                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('url') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                    <label for="url">Url</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="url" name="url" placeholder="URL" value="{{ $link->url }}">
                    @if($errors->has('url'))
                        <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('url') }}</span>
                    @endif
                </div>
                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('description') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                    <label for="description">Description</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="description" name="description" placeholder="description">{{ $link->description }}</textarea>
                    @if($errors->has('description'))
                        <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('description') }}</span>
                    @endif
                    @endforeach
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default submit-btn">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

web/route controller:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::post('/submit', function (Request $request) {
  $data = $request->validate([
      'title' => 'required|max:255',
      'url' => 'required|url|max:255',
      'description' => 'required|max:255',
  ]);

  $link = tap(new App\Link($data))->save();

  return redirect('/');
});

use App\Link;

Route::delete('/link/{link}', function (Link $link) {
  // Link::destroy($link);
  $link->delete();
  return redirect('/');
});

Route::PUT('/link/{link}', function (Link $link) {
  $link->update();
  return redirect('/');
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a design pattern, it's often recommended to separate your controller from the routes. The reason your edit is not updating is that you're not providing the model with the data from the request:-

```
Route::PUT('/link/{link}', function (Request $request, Link $link) {
    $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required|max:255',
        'url' => 'required|url|max:255',
        'description' => 'required|max:255',
    ]);
    $link->update($request->all());
    return redirect('/');
});
```

In a controller, you could abstract away the validation logic to a validation helper function to avoid duplicating code.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! Although this is the error after implementation:                    
ErrorException (E_DEPRECATED)
Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::all() should not be called statically

Comment: Hi Ruan, this has to do with your include statement, see:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28573860/laravel-requestall-should-not-be-called-statically

Comment: Change `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` to `use Request;` or instead of that use `request()->all();` helper

Comment: Thanks I fixed it by changing this:      $link->update($request::all());     to this:    $link->update($request->all());